# Fitting a sinusoid to $n$ points

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, system-identification

I was inspired by a [closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377666/equation-of-a-cosine-graph-given-two-points) to consider the following problem.

Given a set of $n$ points $\{ (x_i, y_i) , i = 1,..., n \}$ where $n \ge 4 $, find the sinusoid function of the form

$ y = f(x) = a \cos (k x )+ b \sin (k x) + c $

that fits these points, assuming they do lie on a single sinusoid.

**My attempt:**

Define the error function

$E = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left( a \cos (k x_i) + b \sin (k x_i) + c - y_i \right)^2 $

Then find its partial derivatives $\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial a}, \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial b}, \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial c}, \dfrac{\partial E}{\partial k} $, set them to zero, and numerically solve the resulting nonlinear system of $4$ equations in the parameters $a,b,c,k$.

**EDIT:** I have implemented this method of solving for the parameters by solving the nonlinear system of the $4$ partial derivatives being equal to zero, but it did not work as I hoped it would (it diverged).  So I modified the method and used the steepest descent (the simplest minimization algorithm) to minimize the error function, with $n = 8$, and it did converge, but it needs more testing over several choice of parameters and different number of points.

**My Question:**

I wonder if a non-numerical method exists for finding $a,b,c,k$ in closed form.

Thank you for any hints or full solutions.

Comment: I assume there is nothing special about fitting 4 points (one could run your procedure for n points). Your procedure is essentially a case of nonlinear least squares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares

Comment: This kind of nonlinear least-squares fit is quite standard. The usual problem, without convexity, is to decide if you are reaching local or global   minima in the optimization procedure.

Comment: You make explicit expressions $a(k)$, $b(k)$ and $c(k)$ and you just have a nonlinear equation in $k$ to solve.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How do I make these explicit expressions $a(k), b(k)$ and $c(k)$ ? Can you elaborate on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the general case of $n$ data points*

Suppose that $k$ is known. Define for this value $C_i=\cos(kx_i)$ and $S_i=\sin(kx_i)$. So, the model is
$$y=a \,C+b \,S+c$$ Use the normal equations
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=a \sum_{i=1}^n C_i+\sum_{i=1}^n S_i+n \,c$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n C_i\,y_i=a \sum_{i=1}^n C^2_i+b\sum_{i=1}^n C_i\,S_i+c\, \sum_{i=1}^n C_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n S_i\,y_i=a \sum_{i=1}^n  C_i\,S_i+b\sum_{i=1}^n S^2_i+c\, \sum_{i=1}^n S_i$$

Solve explicitly these three linear equations to have $a(k)$, $b(k)$ and $c(k)$. So now, you just need to minimize
$$E(k) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( a(k) \cos (k x_i) + b(k) \sin( k x_i )+ c(k) - y_i \right)^2$$ which you can plot to locate more or less its minimum. At this point, start a Newton method using numerical derivatives to make $E'(k)=0$.

Comment: I tried your method and it worked like a charm !!  Thank you very much.